# What benefits will going into the cloud with snappy provide?

Tags: ubuntu-core

This is a from-scratch rewrite of a previously posted question.

So this move towards snappy seems to be the beginnings of a migration of Ubuntu users into a Cloud OS.

If I have files in the cloud, the vendor can read them. That's a security violation because they don't own them. Sure, you have to sign over your rights to those files in order to use the service but that is why many of us don't use those services. Google reads your email, for example. If they didn't or couldn't then your Gmail wouldn't be as search-able. Bottom line: The vendor can see and read any data you put in the cloud because it's on their machines. Access to private data is precisely why corporations are pushing the cloud and many of us find this unacceptable for a host of reasons.

Given that the Cloud is mostly unsecured by it's nature, i.e. all the major  corporations wanting access to data that should be private, what benefits will we get from The Cloud in trade for our privacy and freedom?  ...unless it can be secured by the user prior to any other access, of course. That means encrypting all files, email, tweets, chats and IMs before it even gets to the cloud such that the vendor has no mis-usable information. Protonmail does this and there may be others.

Also, why is more library redundancy and less performance better than no library redundancy and better performance?